# vba select range for table

Tags: vba, range

I want to select the range for a table.
For this, I am looking at the last row and column and want to select everything from the first cell to the combination row and column.

```
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(outsheet)
    Dim rngRow As Range

    Set rngRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)
    rngRow.Select

    Dim rngCol As Range
    Set rngCol = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    rngCol.Select

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range(rngRow.Column, rngCol.row))
```

However, the code fails in the last line with "range failed".
What is wrong, or is there a better approach?

After this, I want to call

```
    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "Tabelle1"
```

Comment: You might want to prefix all calls to `Range` with `ws.`. And you are missing a `Set`: `Set rng = ... `

Comment: BTW, avoid using [Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) Here they aren't even useful.

Comment: You could use: Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion instead of rng in ListObjects.add

Comment: Select is only for debugging. I do not intend to use it.

Comment: I updated the code but it still fails.@EvR: How reliable is CurrentRegion ?

Comment: Code below as answer, works on my system. As long there's an empty column right and a empty row under your range for your Table, currentregion will work

Comment: `rngCol` and  `rngRow` are two diagonally opposed corners of your range, you can just use `Set rng = ws.Range(rngCol, rngRow)` to define the final range.

Comment: and your code failed because it's either `ws.Range(rngRow, rngCol)` or `ws.Cells(rngRow.Row, rngCol.Column)`. Range takes Ranges as argument, while Cells takes indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:(as long Tabelle1 doesnot excist)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(outsheet)
    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "Tabelle1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range(rngRow.Column, rngCol.row))
```

should be

```
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Cells(rngCol.row, rngRow.Column))
```

or simply

```
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range(rngCol, rngRow))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `UsedRange`?

```
Sub rangeselect()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange
    rng.Select

End Sub
```